# Does catch exception by reference need to be deleted?

Tags: c++, g++

I'm creating a customized exception class

```
class my_error: public std::exception
{

public:

    //! Constructs parse error
    my_error(const char* param_msg, std::string param_reason) throw()
    {
        msg = param_msg;
        reason = param_reason;
    }
    ~my_error() throw() {}

private:
    string msg;
    string reason

};
```

and throw it with this way

```
throw my_error("something wrong", "coffee is too hot");
```

and catch with

```
catch(ems_error& ex) { 
// do somehitng here 
}
```

question: should i call delete on this ex variable? currently my program works fine without delete but I'm worry abbout memory leak

Comment: No need to call delete. You'd only need to if had created the exception on the heap (by calling `new`)

Comment: What would you delete? You don't have a pointer!

Comment: LOL, thanks guys for confirming!

Comment: Mark Ransom, a pointer does not indicate that something is on the heap. Your comment may be misunderstood.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Exception objects are automatically destroyed after being handled. (See C++11 §15.1/4)